# Discrepancy in secp256k1 signature generation

Tags: signature

I'll get straight to the point here.

There are two different programs I'm looking at. They both use secp256k1 to deterministically sign data (RFC6979) & provide the results online in-browser. However, both programs produce different DER-encoded signatures and I'm honestly baffled at this point as to why.

Program #1: https://paulmillr.com/noble/

Program #2: https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/sigs2

Since program #2 generates the private key randomly, I'd suggest running that first. You can take the private key (which is displayed) and throw that into program #1 and also duplicate the message to see what I'm talking about.

I'll show you all in live time below as well.

**Program #1**

[image: f]

Here, the message to be hashed is "avalanche" and the private key to sign it was 0x9fdd656817fe425361d41fa46911012c2e419e3774377c54c9a427c373e10919.

If we scroll further down the page we'll see the DER encoded signature they provided for that was: 3045022100e0842095f8b764b2b5ce9ba1d4541cbd9048f7e9df6e2c3e075b2f34ee5ceaa9022002ebf7ece15fad53213ab0ffb60df71b4459a50f5365eb47785766859c94db24

[image]

With that in mind, let's visit the next program.

**Program #2**

[image]

We input the same values here and that yields us a DER encoded value of: 304402202b12266521e5129146cbccfc6e4a10d6b4cfea081c8cbf237a56997d2843c01f0220370e8d87b611605f7a90922e0083184d9990066dc83def2a5fd017a4aa8ed606

[image]

I diff'd the two outputs. I don't know if that's me just hyper reading into this, but who knows.

[image]

**Addressing Some Potential Premature Responses**

1. "One must be legit and the other one isn't": I've went through the code for both projects. They both use HMAC-SHA256 and pipe that input into the 'k' (random nonce) for generating the signature
2. They both use the same hash signature (sha256)
3. Both are open source
4. Program 2 uses javascript, program 1 uses Python. The first uses pure python. The second was audited by cure53 for its cryptographic soundness.
5. To my understanding, both programs are encoding the data the same way.

I'm really stumped at this point and any help would be **immensely appreciated**. Thank you.

Comment: The question numbers the programs inconsistently. A brief attempt to replicate tends to confirm there is a discrepancy in the signatures for the same message and same private key; that it's not in how the private key is turned to public key; nor in the hash (or encoding) of the message. The most likely seems to be some divergence in the deterministic computation of the ephemeral secret $k$ from private key and hash of message.